# Launch file error

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I modified other's launch file to add my own parameters in the code. First is the new launch file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
<arg name="uri" default="radio://0/80/250K" />
<arg name="frame" default="/crazyflie" />
<arg name="joy_dev" default="/dev/input/js0" />
<arg name="x" default="3" />
<arg name="y" default="0" />
<arg name="z" default="0" />
<arg name="x2" default="0.9" />
<include file="$(find crazyflie_driver)/launch/crazyflie_server.launch">
</include>

<group ns="crazyflie">
<include file="$(find crazyflie_driver)/launch/crazyflie_add.launch">
  <arg name="uri" value="$(arg uri)" />
  <arg name="tf_prefix" value="crazyflie" />
  <arg name="enable_logging" value="True" />
</include>
<node name="joy" pkg="joy" type="joy_node" output="screen">
  <param name="dev" value="$(arg joy_dev)" />
</node>

<node name="joystick_controller" pkg="crazyflie_demo" type="controller.py" output="screen">
  <param name="use_crazyflie_controller" value="True" />
</node>

<include file="$(find crazyflie_controller)/launch/crazyflie2.launch">
  <arg name="frame" value="$(arg frame)" />
  <param name="x2"    value="$(arg x2)" />
</include>

<node name="pose" pkg="crazyflie_demo" type="publish_pose.py" output="scree$
  <param name="name" value="goal" />
  <param name="rate" value="30" />
  <param name="x" value="$(arg x)" />
  <param name="y" value="$(arg y)" />
  <param name="z" value="$(arg z)" />
</node>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="baselink_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 1 $(arg frame) /crazyflie/base_link 100" />
</group>

<!-- run vicon bridge -->
<include file="$(find mocap_optitrack)/launch/mocap.launch"/>

<!-- run rviz -->
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find crazyflie_description)/urdf/crazyflie.urdf.xacro" />
<node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find crazyflie_demo)/launch/crazyflie_pos.rviz" required="true" />

</launch>
```

And the error

```
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed (invalid token): line 35, column 6 The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Line 35, is `<param name="name" value="goal" />` The launch I modified is all the parts related to "x2", the new parameter I need in the modified code. So I don't think it is the "line 35 column 6" which I didn't change cause the error. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271425/launch-file-error/) by [jason](https://answers.ros.org/users/29292/jason/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2017-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error tells you what the problem is and where to find it.

```
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed (invalid token):
```

tells you that there is something wrong with the XML syntax of your file.

```
line 35, column 6 The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

tells you that the problem is at *approximately* line 35. Many times errors come before where you're told the error is. In this case it's at line 32 where you have a malformed `node` tag.

Change

```
<node name="pose" pkg="crazyflie_demo" type="publish_pose.py" output="scree$
```

to

```
<node name="pose" pkg="crazyflie_demo" type="publish_pose.py" output="screen">
```

Notice how I added the missing quotation mark and closing `>` and changed `$` to `n`.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jason](https://answers.ros.org/users/29292/jason/) on 2017-09-24**:
Thanks. I have no idea how could I make this mistake with "copy" and "paste". Anyway, thank you very much.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-24**:
No problem. Glad to help.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-25**:
@jason: the `$` is typically used by text-based/console editors to indicate that the line is longer than the width of the text editor window. If you then copy-paste using mouse selection, you copy incomplete lines.